# How to regex_replace in 10th position from CLOB field

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have this code:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'^name\[([[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[[:alpha:][:space:][:punct:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:][:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:][:punct:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:][:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:][:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|([[:digit:][:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|([[:alpha:]]*).*','[p1=\10]') as replaced

FROM  Dual
```

**Editor's note**: the above is a single unreadable line. Here is the same regex with line breaks for readability:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name
                      ,'^name\[([[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[[:alpha:][:space:][:punct:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:digit:][:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:digit:][:punct:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:digit:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:digit:][:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:digit:][:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:digit:][:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|
                       ([[:alpha:]]*).*'
        ,'[p1=\10]') as replaced

FROM  Dual
```

I want to select tenth position out of it. I am able to select until nine positions  but I am not able to make its tenth position on above logic. Any guess or help.

`[p1=\9]` if I use this expression I am able to select nine positions but I want tenth position string from the above expression.

`[p1=\10]` if my expression is like this it's selecting first position's value followed by `0`.

Any help?

Comment: Post an example as what is your input string and what you expect as output.

Comment: what does name string looklike and what a 10th postion with respect to

Comment: Are you sure it returns the ninth position when you use \10? It seems like it should return the first (`\1`) followed by `0`.

Comment: Oracle only supports back references `\1` through `\9`. Also it doesn't appear to support a syntax for identifying non-capturing groups, which would be the other way to solve such a problem.

Comment: I agree with @mjsqu - the actual behaviour of `\10` is to return the first back reference followed by zero. I suspect this is a cut'n'paste error in the original question.

Comment: Input string 


Name[ABCGD |||R|||Registered |||15|||01/13/2012|||Nursing|||WI|||0331|||Sheboygan |||WI|||R0785|||BBB|||D0|||AAA|||CCC]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example of a string that matches your regex:

```
name[a|||b|||c|||d|||0|||e|||f|||1|||g|||h|||i|||j|||k|||l|||m
```

So, you want to return 'h', the tenth field, but \10 returns a0.

If you're only interested in the tenth capturing group and none of the previous ones, then you can just remove the brackets on all capturing groups up to that one, and then use \1.

UPDATE: OP wants 2,3,4,8,9,10 and 12th fields, so just add brackets for those fields.

```
Field | Capture Group number
====================================
2     | \1
3     | \2
4     | \3
8     | \4
9     | \5
10    | \6
12    | \7
```

The code:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(name
,'^name\[[[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]]*\|\|\|
([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
([[[:alpha:][:space:][:punct:]]*)\|\|\|
([[:digit:][:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
[[:digit:][:punct:]]*\|\|\|
[[:alpha:][:space:]]*\|\|\|
[[:alpha:]]*\|\|\|
([[:digit:]]*)\|\|\|
([[:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|
([[:alpha:]]*)\|\|\|
[[:digit:][:alpha:]]*\|\|\|
([[:digit:][:alpha:][:space:]]*)\|\|\|
[[:digit:][:alpha:]]*\|\|\|
[[:alpha:][:space:]]*\|\|\|
[[:alpha:]]*.*','[p1=\1]') as replaced

FROM  Dual
```

(Linebreaks added to the regex for clarity)

I should add that it looks like the broader question you're asking is how to get the tenth field from a triple-pipe delimited string in Oracle, which may be achievable in other ways that don't involve lengthy regexes like this.

Comment: I need 2,3,4,8,9,10th values and 12th values,

Comment: my input string looks like below 

Input string Name[ABCGD |||R|||Registered |||15|||01/13/2012|||Nursing|||WI|||0331|||Sheboygan |||WI|||R0785|||BBB|||D0|||AAA|||CCC]

Comment: So you need to capture 7 values, there are nine groups available so just reorder the brackets. Editing the question now.

Comment: regex101.com/r/Hjf7Ux/2 it same issue like earlier

Comment: It captures `R Registered  15 0331 Sheboygan  WI BBB` from your string. If the regex doesn't work as you intend, use the site to modify the regex. If you're still not happy with the result, ask another question on here about how to split by `|||` as regex might not be the answer.

Comment: I have 16 groups out of it I need 6 groups which is in a different location in a column, the most important is  I want 16th group value in 2 place

Comment: If you want the fields in a different order, or you want to repeat them, just use a different replacement like '`\1\6\1\2\3\4\5\6'`